# Is it possible to wake uv_loop from a different thread?

Tags: libuv

I started playing with libuv and I'm really liking it, however I can't seem to find a way to signal the loop thread from a different thread. What I want to do is something like:

Thread A: blocks on uv_run(uv_default_loop(), UV_DEFAULT_RUN); Let's say it listens on a socket.

Thread B: wakes up the thread that sleeps on uv_default_loop() by means other than writing on the socket, something like uv_loop_signal() ?

Would anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh silly me. Here it is:

```
uv_async_t event;
uv_async_init(uv_default_loop(), &event,eventCB);
uv_async_send(&event);
```